# Sticky footer properties not mobile device compatible

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sticky footer that wil appear at the bottom of my site at all times. It works perfectly on desktop PCs etc. and mobile phones in landscape however when viewing on mobile phones (S4, iPhone etc.) in portrait mode, the footer appears in the middle of the page as opposed to the bottom. I've tried adding different viewport meta tags and have looked up possible solutions however I'm not really getting anywhere - any ideas?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb6Um/)

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -62px;
}

footer, .push {
height: 62px;
}

footer {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
min-width: 870px;
width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    [... content ...]
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<footer>
    [... content ...]
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) or you can use position fixed for a footer.